# How to Maximum update depth exceeded in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render for drag only once, but renders the infinite loops.
i'm use The react Dnd method for this project

this warning is Show : Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

```
chichihandler = (id) => {
    console.log('inApp', id);
    this.setState({
        hoverdID: 123
    })
    console.log("hoverd", this.state.hoverdID)
}
render() {
    return (
        <div className="all">
            <Header />
            <div className='Products_list'  >
                {this.state.productData.map((item) => (
                    <Products key={item.id} item={item} handleDrop={(productId) => this.addItem(productId)} />
                ))}
            </div>
            <div className='Store_list' >
                <div className="storeName" >Store Name</div>
                {this.state.storeData.map((itemS) => (
                    <Store key={itemS.code} itemS={itemS} chichi={(id) => this.chichihandler(id)} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

`storeData` Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { DropTarget } from 'react-dnd'
function collect(connect, monitor) {
    return {
        connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
        hovered: monitor.isOver(),
        item: monitor.getItem()
    }
}
class Store extends Component {
    render() {
        const { connectDropTarget, hovered, itemS } = this.props
        const backcgroundColor = hovered ? 'lightgreen' : ''
        if (hovered) {
            this.props.chichi(itemS.name)
            console.log(itemS.name)
        }
        return connectDropTarget(
            <div>
                <div id={itemS.code} className='Store' style={{ background: backcgroundColor }}>
                    {this.props.itemS.name}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default DropTarget('item', {}, collect)(Store)
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop occurs in the render method of your `Store` component, where it

- calls `this.props.chici(itemS.name)`, which
- calls your `chichiHandler()` function, which
- calls `this.setState()` on the parent component, which
- triggers a re-render, which
- causes `Store` to re-render, which...

It looks like you want the `chichi` function to be called when the user hovers over something, in which case you're better off using the `onMouseOver` prop on the element in question, rather than try to do it with props (see https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events for more info).

In general you should *never* call `setState()` from with in a `render()`, because it tends to cause these sorts of loops.